# What is the preferred approach to derive the kinematics/dynamics of a floating base 3-link robot?

Tags: kinematics, inverse-kinematics, motion-planning, dynamics, jacobian

I would like to derive the kinematics and dynamics of a floating planar robot with two leg links and a hip link while the robot is in free-fall (i.e. no ground contact at the "feet").  This would be similar to the following picture (taken/modified from the Robotics Handbook).  Note that the leg links, B1 & B3, are rigid bodies.  Therefore there are a total of three links (B1, B2 and B3) and two actuated revolute joints (J1 and J2).

[image]

The ultimate goal is to be able to determine the angular velocities required at J1 and J2 in order to reorient the hip link B2 as desired.

I can think of two ways to approach this.

1. Treat the hip link B2 as a floating base of a branched robot with the two legs (B1 and B3) treated as end-effectors.  The hip link is connected to the inertial reference frame via an unactuated 6-DOF joint.
2. Treat the hip link as the end-effector with the distal end of each leg being connected via an unactuated 6-DOF joint to the inertial references frame.  This would therefore be a closed-chain robot.

Which of the two approaches (if either), would be preferred for this task?  What would the the advantages and disadvantages of each approach?  If neither approach works, then suggestions of alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hello, may I know if you've made any progress with this? and what resources have you used so far? thank you.